# Curl and wget not getting the latest committed file from GitHub

Tags: bash, github

I'm using `curl -s -o file.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO/master/file.sh` to update a script file. However, the above command won't get the latest commit right after the push. It takes a while to do so.

Is it as it's supposed to be or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had this working for the last year and now it is not. It doesnt work with `curl` either, so I know its a problem with GitHub. I use this to download basic dotfiles for linux. Arg, very frustrating.. going to open a GH issue.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/46758  looks like this just broke yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your use case, but it is always better to use git pull to get the latest changes.
Github may do some housekeeping operations before making the new changes available at the "raw" url.

Comment: I agree with this, in general; however, it can be also used for deployment purposes, like download-and-install with version control. In that case, git-pull is ovrehead.